# Difference between "->" and "::" in PHP MySQLi OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

Can anyone tell the difference between `mysqli->commit` and `mysqli::commit`?

The header in [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) is `mysqli::commit`, but in examples they use `mysqli->commit`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`->` is used when referring to a member of an object.

`::` is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and is used to refer to a static member of a Class.

Consider the following class:

```
class FooBar {
    public static function fizz() {
        echo "Fizz";
    }

    public function buzz() {
        echo "Buzz";
    }
}
```

You would call the function `buzz()` using `->`:

```
$myFooBar = new FooBar();
$myFooBar->buzz();
```

But would use `::` to call the functon `fizz()`, as it is a static member (a member which doesn't require an instance of the class to be called):

```
FooBar::fizz();
```

---

Also, while we are talking about the difference between **static** members versus **instantiated** members, you cannot use `$this` to refer to the current instance within **static** members. You use [`self`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) instead (no leading `$`) which refers to the current class, or [`parent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) if you want to refer to the parent class, or if you have the pleasure of working with PHP 5.3.0, [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) (which allows for late static binding).

---

The documentation uses `::` to refer to a function inside a class as the class name in the header is not an instance of the class. Still using the same example, a documentation entry referring  to the function `buzz()` would use the following header:

```
FooBar::buzz
```

But unless the documentation specifies it's a static member, you will need to use `->` on an instance to call it:

```
$myFooBar = new FooBar();
$myFooBar->buzz();
```

Comment: Was about to post, but this is pretty spot on. In short answer to John there is no difference. As Andrew states its a convention in the PHP manual to describe a class method as ClassName::methodName

The intention is to use is as an object, i.e. $name->commit() unless it says otherwise in the documentation.

Comment: This answer is amazing. how to do FooBar::fizz()->select("something")->where("something");

Answer (score 5):

`::` is used for **static methods**.

`->` is used for method of an object if you already have the instance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an instance of an object, you use -> to refer to a method inside this instance:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
```

Using :: calls a static method without having to create an instance of the object:

```
Foo::bar();
```

A static method cannot refer to an it's current instance through `$this`, but can refer to itself (current class) by using `self`.

Comment: Calling a non-static member using the scope resolution operator raises an E_STRICT in PHP < 5.3.0 and an E_WARNING in PHP >= 5.3.0.

Comment: And `self` exists to refer to the current class in a static context. It doesn't refer to an  instance, but to itself:  `class A { static function b() { self::c(); } private static function c() { echo 'hello'; } };`

Answer (score 1):

`::` specifies a static (class) method, which is callable without actually instantiating an object. `->` specifies an instance (object) method, for which you need an object instantiated to be able to use.

So for example, if you had a variable `$m` which was an instance of class `mysqli`, you would call `commit` by saying `$m->commit()`, or you could call commit statically by saying `MySQLi::commit()`

Answer (score 0):

:: accesses the class' function without instancing an object.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator is for *object properties*.

The `::` operator is for *class properties*.

Answer (score 0):

in mysqli->commit, mysqli is a instance of MySQLi
in mysqli::commit call a static method

Answer (score 0):

mysqli->commit is a public function and mysqli::commit is a static function the two are php object notations of mysqli class.

Answer (score 0):

usually in php.net documentation :: means that this class has that method. For pratical usage you must follow the example so use the -> sintax.